# Is there a better way to reduce if-statements

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I am not sure how to optimize code when I have many if-statements.
So till now I have

```
 if (input.Contains("triangle"))
 {
     if (input.Contains("rectangular"))
     {

     }
     else if (input.Contains("isosceles"))
     {

     }
     else if (input.Contains("equilateral"))
     {

     }
}
```

I am not sure how I can do that.

Is there is a better way to reduce if-statements?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "better". This is perfectly readable to me. You could reduce nesting, but you'd complicate the conditions.

Comment: I mean, it won't slow down the program

Comment: What you have won't 'slowdown' anything

Comment: Don't worry about micro-optimizations. You can't get much simpler than this. If you were checking the same conditions, then you'd want to optimize, but this is fine.

Comment: For questions such as this, you should try code review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given code already suits its purpose. There is no need for *premature optimizations* here. I will however give you an idea of when if-statements need rephrasing.

Example problem:

> Validate the input. Valid input must not contain spaces or dots. Numbers except 7 are allowed as well.

Not so good code:

```
bool validate(String str) {
    // "!" is read as "not". True becomes false, and vice-versa
    if (!(str.Contains(" "))){
        if (!(str.Contains("."))){
            if (!(str.Contains("7"))){
                Console.WriteLine("Success");
                 return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is what you call **nested conditions**. Too many nested if-statements can be a real *eyesore* and that's when you'll want to fix it. While nested if-statements aren't always bad, it is often a good idea to think of ways to **separate** them, so that the main code is not deeply indented. 
(In this case you might argue combining the conditions into one if-statement using the "||" ('or' operator) or "&&" ('and' operator). That's not wrong, but in more complicated logic, you would often want to separate conditions for easier debugging.)

Slightly better code:

```
bool validate(String str) {
    // "!" is read as "not". True becomes false, and vice-versa
    bool isValid = true;
    if (str.Contains(" ")){
        isValid = false;
    }
    if (str.Contains(".")){
        isValid = false;
    }
    if (str.Contains("7")){
        isValid = false;
    }
    if (isValid){
        Console.WriteLine("Success");
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Another strategy is to use **early exit**.
It basically means check for the unwanted cases first, and if such a case is found, return false immediately.

Better code:

```
bool validate(String str) {
    // Since we are checking for unwanted cases, we won't use the not operator
    if (str.Contains(" ")){
        return false;
    }
    if (str.Contains(".")){
        return false;
    }
    if (str.Contains("7")){
        return false;
    }
    // You could also do 
    // if (str.Contains(" ") || str.Contains(".") || str.Contains("7")) if you want

    // Notice how the main code is not within any if-statement
    Console.WriteLine("Success");
    return true;
}
```

In conclusion:

- Avoid unnecessary nested conditions
- Separate conditions if possible.
- Take advantage of early exit
- Many if-statements are okay, especially if your programs needs to handle many cases. Don't get paranoid spending 75% of your time trying to make premature optimizations. The changes to the if statements do not cause a large difference in speed. However, making them neater does cause a large difference for the programmers reading your code (which might include you).

Comment: Alright nice thanks for your advice